# Is it possible to append Data of audio file in AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, nsdate, avaudioplayer, nsmutabledata

i'hv added 10 audio files (1.m4a,2.m4a,...,10.m4a) in my local project and i convert first part into data and append into `NSMutableData` then load in player. working good.
Now i have button, onClick of button i append 3 parts of music files, but its now playing in `avaudioplayer`. 
Does anyone know how can i do this?

```
 func loadFirstnPlay() {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "1", withExtension: "m4a"){
        if let rawData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
            arrSongsData.append(rawData as Data)
            do {
                avAudioPlyer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: arrSongsData as Data)
                avAudioPlyer.prepareToPlay()
                avAudioPlyer.delegate = self
                avAudioPlyer.play()
                print("Play")
            }catch{
                print("Error : ",error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

onButtonClick

```
 func onButtonClick() {
    for i in 2...4{
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(i)", withExtension: "m4a"){
            if let rawData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
                arrSongsData.append(rawData as Data)
                print("\(i) : ",arrSongsData.length)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onButtonClick` you have to play next audio, right?

Comment: @JayeshThanki yes, but if my previous track is playing then audio data need to append in currently playing Data

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @SemyonTikhonenko nop i use `Extended Audio File Services` to play queue songs, its suitable for my need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play audio one by one then you can also use `AVQueuePlayer` with `AVPlayerItem`.

```
var arrSongItem:[AVPlayerItem] = []
var avQueuePlayer:AVQueuePlayer!

func loadFirstnPlay() {
    for i in 1...10 {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(i)", withExtension: "m4a"){
            let item = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
            arrSongItem.append(item)
        }
    }
    avQueuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: arrSongItem)
    avQueuePlayer.play()
}
```

You can also insert items, remove items and next the current item using `AVQueuePlayer` object.

Ref : [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer)

Comment: yeah! but i want to append playing raw data, like queue. 1st track is playing  then 2nd track need append, not play directly

Comment: you can this `insert(_:after:)` function to insert item dynamically in queue.

Comment: Thanks for replying, i know this, but my main goal is to append NSData in player not item. at the end its work like single file

Comment: so you have to merge audio files in one file and then you have to convert into `NSData` to play audio.

Comment: please refer this link for same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644046/how-to-concatenate-2-or-3-audio-files-in-ios